# Make archive file (.a file) on macos from object file (.o)

Tags: c++, macos, static-libraries

I want to create my own static library. I've watched tutorials on youtube for Linux (I couldn't find any mac tutorials). The tutorials used the command line tool `ar` to turn .o files into .a files. I tried doing this: `ar rs library.o` on mac but it didn't work. How can I do this on a Mac? Thanks.

This is the output:

```
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

`ar rcs mylibrary.a myobjfile.o [...]`